# Android 2.3.3 - Messages: Wrong Status Information in the Conversation Overview

Tags: android, sms, status

On my HTC Desire Z with Android 2.3.3 I get from time to time the problem, that the status information ist wrong. That means status information says, that there is an unread, unsent or failed SMS, but this SMS is already deleted.
Does anybody know, where I can reset this information? It must be stored anywhere in

```
ContentResolver of 
content://mms-sms/conversations or
content://sms/conversations
```

on the thread-level, but I have no idea.
Example: After I deleted a number of failed SMS in the non delivered SMS overview, the status of non delivered SMS was not reset in the Messages conversation overview though in each conversation there wasn't any undelivered SMS left.

**Edit / Work around:**
I could not find a programmatical solution for this problem, but I found a work around: I used GO SMS PRO. At first the same erroneous display appears. But after I stepped into a detailed view of a conversation and go back, the erroneous send status flag is deleted. If I then go back to the stock messaging program and do something, the erroneous display will be deleted there, too. I have to do this for each conversation with a wrong send status display.